# Datetime substitution in Apache - Camel Kubernetes Yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi, s3-kafka-connector

I wanted to deploy S3 kafka sink connector (using Apache Camel) in kubernetes using reference document https://ibm-cloud-architecture.github.io/refarch-eda/scenarios/connect-s3/

DateTime placeholder (**${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS}** used in this Kubernetes deployment file is not resolved. Whereas the ${file:} is resolved.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: s3-sink-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    topics: my-replicated-topic
    camel.sink.url: aws-s3://kafka-s3?keyName=s3-connect/${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS} <-- NOT RESOLVED
    camel.component.aws-s3.configuration.autocloseBody: false
    camel.component.aws-s3.accessKey: ${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/aws-credentials/aws-credentials.properties:aws_access_key_id}  <-- RESOLVED
    camel.component.aws-s3.secretKey: ${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/aws-credentials/aws-credentials.properties:aws_secret_access_key}  <-- RESOLVED
```

I see both ${date:now:yyyyMMdd} and exchangeId in this document (https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html)

Answer (score 0):

As described in this issue: https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector/issues/251 `DateTime placeholders` are not supported yet.

They probably will be according to https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector/issues/252.

Comment: Yes, I am the one created ticket https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector/issues/251. Glad its getting worked on!